# Reload only <Div> not whole form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

Please take a look at this code. I want only to refresh a part of form not whole page. Current code is refreshing whole page. No need to look for database error as all entries are going in database

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#refbutton').click(function() {
        var val = $('#refinfo').val();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'selectbox.php',
          data: 'val=' + val,
          success: function(html) {
            alert(html);
            window.location.reload();
          }
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Html Code

```
    <form>
    <table>
    <tr>
            <td >Name</td>
            <td ><input name="name" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td><textarea name="address" ></textarea></td>
        </tr>
<div id="mydiv">
    <tr>
            <td>Reference</td>

            <td>

                <select data-placeholder="Choose a reference..." class="chosen-select" name ="reference1" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
                <option value="default">Please Select</option>
                <?php

                $sql="select * from reference ";
                //echo $sql;
                $tbl=mysql_query($sql);
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($tbl))
                {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['reference'];?>"><?php echo $row['reference'];?></option>
                <?php }?>


              </select>

            </td>

            <td>
                <input name="reference2" type="text" id="refinfo" ></input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="Button_ref" id="refbutton" type="button" value="Add Reference"></td>

        </tr>
</div>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Remove `window.location.reload();` and use `$('div').html(html)`

Comment: @ShaunakD That way my entry wont be added into select box

Comment: Append the value to the select box instead of reloading the page.

Comment: @lshettyl I want to add value from reference2 to db and then fetch value from db in selectbox

Comment: Bro I think you should have to take look at what is synchronous and asynchronous in JavaScript? as of now.

Comment: What is the value of `html` in `success: function(html)` ?

Comment: @lshettyl echo "Data Added";

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid as you can't have `<div id="mydiv">` between `TR`s. Why do you even want it? If you want a div, you must have it in a `TD` or outside the `TABLE`. I think, all you want is the new option added to the DB, append it to the select box and populate `<div id="mydiv">` with the returned `html`. Try the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#refbutton').click(function() {
        var val = $('#refinfo').val();
        var $select = $(".chosen-select");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'selectbox.php',
            data: { val: val },
            success: function(html) {
                $("#mydiv").html(html);
                //This would append the new option to the select box without page reload
                $select.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kzgtaku/) with your HTML corrected. I have put the `<div id="mydiv">` just before the form.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<form>
    <table>
    <tr>
            <td >Name</td>
            <td ><input name="name" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td><textarea name="address" ></textarea></td>
        </tr>
<div id="mydiv">
    <tr>
            <td>Reference</td>

            <td>
                <div class="my-div">NEW HTML GOES HERE</div>

                <select data-placeholder="Choose a reference..." class="chosen-select" name ="reference1" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
                <option value="default">Please Select</option>
                <?php

                $sql="select * from reference ";
                //echo $sql;
                $tbl=mysql_query($sql);
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($tbl))
                {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['reference'];?>"><?php echo $row['reference'];?></option>
                <?php }?>


              </select>

            </td>

            <td>
                <input name="reference2" type="text" id="refinfo" ></input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="Button_ref" id="refbutton" type="button" value="Add Reference"></td>

        </tr>
</div>
    </table>
    </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#refbutton').click(function() {
        var val = $('#refinfo').val();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'selectbox.php',
          data: 'val=' + val,
          success: function(html) {
            $('.my-div').html(html);
          }
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: This would only show value of html, and I would have to reload the whole page manually for data to be shown in select-box which of course will remove text entered in other textboxes

Comment: @swinn If you want to change a code in a ```<div>``` or ```<select>``` then you use the same jQuery code. Please don't expect me to write your application..